# MAUI updating Label text on Slider value change using Label.SetBinding()

Tags: c#, maui

I've followed example from documentation on how to use [BindableObjectExtensions.SetBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.bindableobjectextensions.setbinding?view=net-maui-7.0) and it works fine but then I've wanted to extend it so that Label text would change on Slider value change but it doesn't do that.

I know you could achieve this with XAML just fine but I need it to be C# Content page.

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
public class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public PersonViewModel vm = new PersonViewModel
    {
        Name = "John Doe",
        Company = "Xamarin"
    };

    public NewPage1()
    {
                
        var label = new Label();
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name"); // "Name" is the property on the view model
        label.BindingContext = vm;
        Debug.WriteLine (label.Text); // prints "John Doe"
        var slider = new Slider();
        slider.ValueChanged += Slider_ValueChanged;

        var layout = new StackLayout();
        layout.Add(label);
        layout.Add(slider);
        Content = layout;
    }

    private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double value = e.NewValue;
        Debug.WriteLine(value); // prints slider's value from 0 to 1
        vm.Name = value.ToString();

    }
  
}
```

Below is an image of it working fine on initial load but dragging a slider does not update a Label, any help would be appreciated. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Your vm is not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged... So changing property will not be reflected in binding

Comment: see the linked duplicate - the answer is exactly the same for your problem - you need to use `Observable`, which is the same as `INotifyPropertyChanged` as @Selvin mentions